# Correct tense to use when two subjects are in different times

Tags: tense, past-tense, present-tense, tense-agreement

For example:

> The Soviet Union and the People's Republic of China **were/are** communist.

I am unsure of which to use because the first part of the subject implies the past tense while the second part of the subject implies the present tense.

Comment: Even today, you can say "The Soviet Union and the People's Republic of China *were* communist." as a blanket statement, because at some time in the past they were communist. Your example doesn't indicate different times when referring to the two countries.

Answer (score 1):

There is no possible way in which you can make two subjects share the same verb if there is a temporal inconsistency. The only solution I can think of is:

- The Soviet Union **used to be/was**, and the People's Republic of China (still) **is**, communist.